# Stripe Elements React - how to get stripe data from parent component?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I have set up the Stripe element payment form in `_CardForm` component and want to execute the payment process in `Checkout` component which is parent component of `_CardForm`.

However, I can't get the stripe data from  in `_CardForm` component. How do I get the stripe data from child component?

```
const {
  CardElement,
  StripeProvider,
  Elements,
  injectStripe,
} = ReactStripeElements

class _CardForm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.props.userPay}>
        <CardElement />
        <button>Pay</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}
const CardForm = injectStripe(_CardForm)

class Checkout extends React.Component {
  userPay(){
    // PROBLEM: Can't get stripe data from <CardElement />
    console.log(this.props.stripe) // undefined
    this.props.stripe.createToken().then(payload => console.log(payload))
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Checkout">
        <h1>Available Elements</h1>
        <Elements>
          <CardForm userPay={this.userPay.bind(this)} />
        </Elements>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <StripeProvider apiKey="pk_RXwtgk4Z5VR82S94vtwmam6P8qMXQ">
      <Checkout />
    </StripeProvider>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.App'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is difficult for me to test, but it should clear up a few things that are not shown in the documentation.

Also, it goes without saying that you've got to load Stripe correctly in the first place. I can give some pointers in that area as well, but I'll need to know more about how you're trying to load it.

```
const {
  CardElement,
  StripeProvider,
  Elements,
  injectStripe,
} = ReactStripeElements

class CardForm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.props.userPay}>
        <CardElement onReady={this.props.cardRef} />
        <button>Pay</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

class Checkout extends React.Component {
  userPay = (event) => {
    const testName = "John Doe";

    if (this.cardElement) {
      this.props.stripe
        .createToken(
          this.cardElement,
          { name: testName } // add additional information here, such as name and address, if outside card element
        )
        .then(({ token }) => {
          const tokenString = token.id; // you actually want token.id to send to your server and then to the stripe API
          // code to send tokenString to your server, which will then send it to stripe's API
        });
    }
  };

  cardRef = (element) => {
    if (element) {
      this.cardElement = element;
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Checkout">
        <h1>Available Elements</h1>
          <CardForm
            cardRef={this.cardRef}
            userPay={this.userPay}
          />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const StripeCheckout = injectStripe(Checkout);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <StripeProvider apiKey="pk_RXwtgk4Z5VR82S94vtwmam6P8qMXQ">
        <Elements>
          <StripeCheckout />
        </Elements>
    </StripeProvider>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.App'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm trying this out but does not seem to be working. first of all, moving `injectStripe` to `injectStripe(Checkout);` gives me an error message saying `injectStripe is outside of <Elements>`

Comment: In the `userSingup` function, `console.log(this.cardElement)` is showing `t {_emit: ƒ, _once: ƒ, _removeAllListeners: ƒ, _on: ƒ, _userOn: ƒ, …}` but `console.log(this.props.stripe)` still shows `undefined`

Comment: @Ohsik sorry about that. I can solve the first error with the edit above for sure. this.props.stripe should show up after that.

Comment: YES, it shows up now! Thank you. I have one more question. By doing that, I wrapped `<Elements>` around `<App />` component which looks like `ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <StripeProvider apiKey="pk_RXwtgk4Z5VR82S94vtwmam6P8qMXQ">
      <Elements>
        <App />
      </Elements>
    </StripeProvider>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);` is this okay? or I should move `<StripeProvider /> and <Elements>` to my route which is child of `App` component.

Comment: @Ohsik you can go as high or as low as you’d like up the chain - as long as your above injectStripe. Stripe recommends you go higher up the chain. They say they can better monitor everything that way. Then again, why load these stripe components if you don’t need to. It’s up to you. In my implementation, I added it to the child route instead of App, using your terminology.

Comment: @Ohsik sorry for my poor grammar above haha. Did that answer your question? Did everything workout?

Comment: Yes, it works now! thank you for the help! I noticed that it actually works even without `cardRef={this.cardRef}` function by location `injectStripe ` and `<Elements>` at the right place.

Comment: @Ohsik ah good to know.. that must be why they leave out the cardElement part in the documentation.